# Displaying upcoming Calendar Events - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-calendar-api

I'm trying out Android Studio for the first time, testing out the Smart Mirror SDK from Max Braun:
https://github.com/maxbbraun/mirror

I've gotten everything compiled and working, but I'm trying to add 1 extra piece of functionality. I want a simple text field that displays the upcoming events of the day from a google calendar, like this : https://www.xda-developers.com/files/2013/12/iG9Qdm8.png (Just a text list of the events, possibly the start/end times).

I haven't been able to find any resources to help me figure out how to go about this. Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Android's built-in Calendar Provider to obtain data about your events. I strongly suggest you visit the following link which includes examples you can use in your code:

- [Calendar provider overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#query)